# Is it possible to exchange pathnames between Webview2 and native code?

Tags: javascript, c++, webview2

I have a C++ app that uses WebView2 as UI component. Native-side code and web-side code communicate via a host object. That works great, but:
I want to let the user (for example) drag and drop files to a drop box on the UI, hand the path names over to the client C++ app, which should read and process the files. Butfor this I would need the full path names (on the host).
I have currently no example for the other way round, but I could imagine to hand a path name to JavaScript which should the read and process this file.

I couldn't find any documentation neither on WebView2, nor in the [File Aystem Access API](https://developer.chrome.com/articles/file-system-access/) on the Browser side (Java Script).

I know that there are security issues for real web apps, but - hey - this is a native component anyway!

So here is my code in JavaScript:

```
butOpenFile.addEventListener('click', async () => {
  // Destructure the one-element array.
  [fileHandle] = await window.showOpenFilePicker();
  // Do something with the file handle.
});
```

How can I use *fileHandle *to retrieve the full path of the selected file, that the hostObject can use to open and process the file? (Note: *fileHandle.name* only has the name.ext-part of the path)

Answer (score 0):

There's a recently added API (currently experimental) that let's you post a File DOM object to native code and have it show up on native with the file path of the File DOM object.

It was added in SDK version 1.0.1671-prerelease ([release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/release-notes?tabs=dotnetcsharp#experimental-features))

Here is the [WebMessage objects API spec](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/blob/a8d7435c65878d0d6c0b3cde2f56504d731480ac/specs/WebMessageObjects.md).

I haven't tried the following, but based on the sample code from the spec and your code above it should be something like the following:

```js
// Script running in WebView2
butOpenFile.addEventListener('click', async () => {
  // Destructure the one-element array.
  [fileHandle] = await window.showOpenFilePicker();
  // Post the file handle to the native code
  chrome.webview.postMessageWithAdditionalObjects("FilesDropped", [fileHandle]);

});
```

```cs
// ...
// Somewhere in initialization
webView.CoreWebView2.WebMessageReceived += WebView_WebMessageReceivedHandler;
// ...

void WebView_WebMessageReceivedHandler(object sender, CoreWebView2WebMessageReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    List<string> paths = new List<string>();
    foreach (var additionalObject in args.AdditionalObjects)
    {
        if (additionalObject is CoreWebView2File file)
        {
            paths.Add(file.Path);
        }
    }
    // Do something with the array of paths.
}
```

Comment: That looks promising. Thank you for the links

Comment: But unfortunately it doesn't seem to be included in 1.0,1671-prerelease yet - sigh

Comment: What don't you see working yet? I see `CoreWebView2File` and `CoreWebView2WebMessageReceived.AdditionalObjects` in the [1.0.1671-prerelease nuget package](https://www.fuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.WebView2/1.0.1671-prerelease/lib/netcoreapp3.0/Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.dll/Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core/CoreWebView2WebMessageReceivedEventArgs#P%3AMicrosoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2WebMessageReceivedEventArgs.AdditionalObjects)

Comment: Hmmh_ I can see it too in a C# project, but I can't see it in the C++ header files; nor can the compiler. Are there different versions?

Comment: In C++ you need to look in the webview2experimental.idl header and the interfaces are `ICoreWebView2ExperimentalFile` and `ICoreWebView2ExperimentalWebMessageReceivedEventArgs::AdditionalObjects`

Comment: Thanks again. I think I was not able to spell the word Experimental; It's there!